# Canceling Event (onchange) or retrieving the old value in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am trying to cancel the 'onchange' event for a  element after capturing the selected value. Basically just to capture the selected value and return the select element selected item to where it was. How can i do this in Blazor?

```
<select @onchange="onSelectFilter">
 <option value="0">Select a filter</option>
 <option value="1">Filter 1</option>
 <option value="2">Filter 2</option>
</select> 

@code
{

 private void onSelectFilter(ChangeEventArgs args)
 {
   var val = int.Parse(args.Value.ToString());

   if (val != 0)
   {
     //do something

     //reset the value to 0
     args.Value = 0;
    }
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

much simpler way to do it just in C#

```
@page "/"

<select @bind="Selected" class="form-control">
 <option value="0">Select a filter</option>
 <option value="1">Filter 1</option>
 <option value="2">Filter 2</option>
</select> 

<h1>@Captured</h1>

@code
{
    int Captured;

    int _Selected;
    private int Selected
    {
        get{return _Selected;}
        set{
             Captured = value; //store the captured value
             _Selected = 0;   //reset the drop down
           }
    }

}
```

you can go even more minimal with  this @code block

```
@code
{
    int Captured;

    int Selected
    {
        get{return 0;}  // reset the select
        set{Captured = value;} //store the captured value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @david ! that is exactly how i solved it! binding to a prop and controlling the getter and the setter or the prop.

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1: `InterOp`

This solution works with a bit of JS and [InterOp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0). After get new value, the code uses JS to change `select` value to previous one.

**Blazor code:**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<select id="mySelect" @onchange="onSelectFilter" class="form-control">
 <option value="0">Select a filter</option>
 <option value="1">Filter 1</option>
 <option value="2">Filter 2</option>
</select> 

<h1>@captured</h1>

@code
{

    private string v;
    private string captured;
    private async void onSelectFilter(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        v = (string)args.Value;
        captured = v;

        v="0";
        await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(  //<--- Interop
            "NewSelectValue",
            "mySelect",
            v);
    }
}
```

**The JS code** (for example on `_Host.cshtml` file ):

```
<script>
    window.NewSelectValue = (id, newVal) => {
        let e = document.getElementById(id);
        e.value=newVal;
    }        
</script>
```

## Option 2: Only `C#`

You can do it forcing DOM changes from Blazor code, two steps. Notice I added `value="@v"` to `select` tag:

```
<select @onchange="onSelectFilter" value="@v" class="form-control">
 <option value="0">Select a filter</option>
 <option value="1">Filter 1</option>
 <option value="2">Filter 2</option>
</select> 

<h1>@captured</h1>

@code
{

    private string v;
    private string captured;
    private async void onSelectFilter(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        // step 1: 
        v = (string)args.Value; // set new value
        StateHasChanged();    
        await Task.Delay(1);    // flush UI changes

        // do tasks:
        captured = v;

        // step 2: 
        v="0";                  // set default value
        StateHasChanged();    
        await Task.Delay(1);    // flush UI changes
    }
}
```

## Result:

[image: screenshot sample]

Comment: Thank you, I know in javascript this can be performed and your solution works perfectly here, but I shied away from going there as the promise of Blazor is a javascript free coding. However, I could achieve my goal resetting the value or canceling the event by doing only c#, I am going to post this in a while

Comment: Wow, nice! Waiting to see it.

Comment: @SamerAwajan, I waited for your answer, finally, I posted my own using only c#.